# ASP.NET MVC Show Error Message or Page When User's Access Level is Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I learned I can redirect the user to a different page like this http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-vb but I am wondering if there is a better way?  Also, how can I just send an error message, instead of doing a redirect to a different view?

For instance, here is my code:

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Administrator")>
Public Class CompanyController
```

Could I add something like an error message to this if the user logs in but doesn't have the right credentials?  Could I set an error in the ViewBag.Error?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: My preference for this type of situation is to use fluent security (http://www.fluentsecurity.net/). It's available on nuget and it might help you. +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the Authorize attribute is to prevent access to the controller action if the user is not allowed. It doesn't execute the action at all and redirects to the LogOn action by default. The fact that the original action was not executed means that the view was not rendered.

If you don't want to get redirected to the LogOn action but create some custom view that will be rendered you could write a custom Authorize attribute and override the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method:

```
Public Class MyAuthorizeAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        Dim result = New ViewResult()
        result.ViewName = "Forbidden"
        result.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "oops, you are not allowed"
        filterContext.Result = result
End Sub
End Class
```

and then define the `~/Views/Shared/Forbidden.vbhtml` view that will be rendered:

```
<h3>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</h3>
```

and finally decorate your controller with this custom attribute:

```
<MyAuthorize(Roles:="Administrator")>
Public Class CompanyController
```

Comment: Thank you.  That looks good.  Where do I put the MyAuthorizeAttribute method?

Comment: You decorate your controllers/actions with it, the same way you was using the Authorize attribute.

Comment: So, I just put MyAuthorizeAttribute in the controller I want to use it in?  For example, place the code block in ArticleController.vb?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own Authorization filter in MVC and do whatever you need it to.

You will need to create a class that implements [IAuthorizationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx).
You can have this authorization filter add stuff to ViewBag.Error instead of redirecting to another action if that's what you wanted to do. I'm not sure how useful that message will be if you don't provide a way for your user to authenticate, though.